# Missing all VI descriptions in the llb

Tags: labview

I made a project with a few VIs in it. Every VI had its own VI description in that project. Then I build a llb from this VIs, to use them in several other project. The llb itself works as intended, but the VI description of every VI in this library is missing. What could have caused this? How can that be fixed?

I'm using LabVIEW 2016.

Comment: I spoke with developers of LabVIEW. Nothing known would cause this, and if that were common in LV2016, it would definitely be known by now. You may need to speak with NI tech support to get this resolved. Try again, perhaps using a different way of creating the LLB... if you used LLB Manager, maybe try Save As into an LLB. That's the best help I can offer.

Comment: Thanks for effort. I saved the description now in the llb. But i will contact the tech support, as you suggested.